# polyphonic audio playback with node.js on raspberry pi

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

I've been trying to create polyphonic WAV playback with node.js on raspberry pi 3 running latest raspbian:

- shelling out to aplay/mpg123/some other program - allows me to only play single sound at once
- I tried combination of https://github.com/sebpiq/node-web-audio-api and https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-speaker (sample code below) but audio quality is very low, with a lot of distortions

Is there anything I'm missing here? I know I could easily do it in another programming language (I was able to write C++ code with SDL, and Python with pygame), but the question is if it's possible with node.js :)

Here's my current web-audio-api + node-speaker code:

```
var AudioContext = require('web-audio-api').AudioContext;
var Speaker      = require('speaker');
var fs           = require('fs');

var track1       = './tracks/1.wav';
var track2       = './tracks/1.wav';

var context      = new AudioContext();

context.outStream = new Speaker({
  channels:   context.format.numberOfChannels,
  bitDepth:   context.format.bitDepth,
  sampleRate: context.format.sampleRate
});

function play(audioBuffer) {
  if (!audioBuffer) { return; }

  var bufferSource = context.createBufferSource();

  bufferSource.connect(context.destination);
  bufferSource.buffer = audioBuffer;
  bufferSource.loop   = false;
  bufferSource.start(0);
}

var audioData1 = fs.readFileSync(track1);
var audioData2 = fs.readFileSync(track2);

var audioBuffer1, audioBuffer2;

context.decodeAudioData(audioData1, function(audioBuffer) {
  audioBuffer1 = audioBuffer;
  if (audioBuffer1 && audioBuffer2) { playBoth(); }
});

context.decodeAudioData(audioData2, function(audioBuffer) {
  audioBuffer2 = audioBuffer;
  if (audioBuffer1 && audioBuffer2) { playBoth(); }
});

function playBoth() {
  console.log('playing...');

  play(audioBuffer1);
  play(audioBuffer2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> audio quality is very low, with a lot of distortions

According to the WebAudio spec (https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#SummingJunction):

> No [clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(audio)) is applied at the inputs or outputs of the AudioNode to allow a maximum of dynamic range within the audio graph.

Now if you're playing two audio streams, it's possible that summing them results in a value that's beyond the acceptable range, which sounds like - distortions.

Try lowering the volume of each audio stream by first piping them through a [GainNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode) as so:

```
function play(audioBuffer) {
  if (!audioBuffer) { return; }

  var bufferSource = context.createBufferSource();
  var gainNode = context.createGain();
  gainNode.gain.value = 0.5 // for instance, find a good value

  bufferSource.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(context.destination);
  bufferSource.buffer = audioBuffer;
  bufferSource.loop   = false;
  bufferSource.start(0);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a [DynamicsCompressorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DynamicsCompressorNode), but manually setting the gain gives you more control over the output.

Comment: Gain is not the issue (tested), sound isn't overdriven, but clicks and pops (has empty "breaks"); also I'm not working here with browser WebAudio API, but node.js implementation of it, which might(?) differ from browser one.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly answer-worthy but I can't post comments at the moment ><

I had a similar problem with an app made using js audio api and the, rather easy fix, was lowering the quality of the audio and changing the format.

In your case what I could think of is setting the bit depth&sampling frequency as low as possible without affecting the listener's experience (e.g. 44.1kHz and 16 bit depth).

You might also try changing the format, wav, in theory, should be quite good at the job of not being CPU intensive, however, there are other uncompressed formats (e.g. .aiff)

You may try using multiple cores of the pi:

https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Although this may prove a bit complicated, if you are doing the audio-streaming in parallel with other unrelated processes, you could try moving the audio on a separate CPU.

An (easy) thing you could try would be running node with more RAM, although, in your case, I doubt that I possible.

The biggest problem, however, might be the code, sadly enough I am not experienced with the modules you are using and as such can give to real advice on that (hence, why I said this is not answer worthy :p)

Comment: Audio is already 44.1kHz and 16bit depth; it works really well with C++ and Python, so I think there's either something wrong I'm doing with the JS code, or there's something wrong with node-speaker/node-web-audio-api implementations. I think that RAM and CPU shouldn't be a problem since it works in other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

when you create Speaker instant, set parameter like this
`channels = 1` // you can try with 1 or 2 and get the best quantity
`bitDepth = 16`
`sampleRate = 48000` // normally 44100 for speaking and higher for music playing

Answer (score -1):

You can spawn from node 2 `aplay` processes each playing one file. Use `detached: true` to allow node to continue running.

Comment: This doesn't work, even if I open two terminals and play two files at once that way, I think for it to work I would need to set up dmix, but I'd prefer not to require my users to dig in system configs if possible for this to work.